# passing thumb image to other uiview on selecting particular row in UITable+iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I made a table where I used the customcell in the table.

In the cell there are two buttons.

1. Detail
2. Available.

When a user clicks the detail button I want the thumb image to appear in the Imageview of the selected row(cell) to the other view.

When a user clicks the button the user is pushed to another view.

Please help me; how do I get the thumb image into other UIViewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the other UIViewController that you are pushing, add a UIImageView to the XIB file of your view and link it up to something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbImageView;
```

Then when you are pushing your view, set your UIImageView after you push the new view controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
    anotherViewController.thumbImageView = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView; 
    [anotherViewController release];
}
```

Comment: & cdasher Thanks for the reply i got the solution

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add a method to your detail view that takes the image as a parameter for example:
in your header (If your class is called DetailViewController) and assuming you have a UIImageView on the detail page.

```
-(DetailViewController *) initWithImage:(UIImage *)image;
```

in your implementation:

```
-(DetailViewController *) initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
       self.imageView.image = image;
    }

    return self;

}
```

and to use that method:

```
DetailViewController* dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
[myNavigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
[dvc release];  //Don't leak
```

Comment: I like Chris's answer better than my own.  Give his a try, mine is overly complicated.